# Ionic Serve: Accessing google geolocation api via localhost is working, but when the serve address changes its not working

Tags: google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I am a newbie exploring about Ionic Apps.I am running my ionic server on http://localhost:8100. My App need the users current location.
I have added this

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB16sGmIekuGIvYOfNoW9T44377IU2d2Es"></script>
```

in index.html

And my app.js has

```
  var options = {
              enableHighAccuracy: true
          };

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {
              $scope.position = new google.maps.LatLng(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
              console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.position));
          },
          function(error) {
              alert('Unable to get location: ' + error.message);
          }, options);
```

And added the following in config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*://*.googleapis.com/*"/>
```

I got the current location in $scope.position. But the problem comes when I tried running my app in mobile.So,I have connected my ubuntu to my mobile hotspot with IP-192.168.43.86. I tried running my ionic serve on http://192.168.43.86:8100 using

```
ionic serve --address 192.168.43.86
```

Now the above getCurrentPosition function is returning error stating
*only secured origins are allowed*.
So,I'm not sure whats happening there. Both localhost and 192.168.43.86 are http server only. But running the server in localhost has no issue. But changing the address is returning error. Am I missing something? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have whitelisted the IP address you are using to access the maps API in the Google Developer Console. When you are running on a native device, especially iOS, you will also need to include the `cordova-plugin-whitelist` in order to explicitly whitelist unsecured origins. Here is an example of the meta tag I use for development, it goes in the `<head>` tag of your index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'self' data: gap: *;">
```

You can learn more about the cordova whitelist plugin [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist).